# Change src of hover using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, hover

I need to turn off a default hover state.  I have the following code.

```
$(this).attr("id"); 
if ((this.id == "defaultTab") ){
$(img#defaultTab)[0].src.replace("_on","_off");
},
```

All I am telling the code if "this" hover has an id of DefaultTab, then take defaultTabs image src and replace it.

This is throwing me back errors.

Please help.

Thanks

---

I am posting my entire function for review.  What is happening is that "defaultTab" doesn't seem to exist as an object for me to get the src from.

```
// **************  TABs  ********************//

jQuery.preloadImages = function()
{
for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++)
    {
        jQuery("<img>").attr("src", arguments[i]);
    }
} 

// preload images first (can run before page is fully loaded)
$.preloadImages("images/tabs01_off.jpg", "images/tabs01_on.jpg",   "images/tabs02_off.jpg","images/tabs02_on.jpg","images/tabs03_off.jpg","images/tabs03_on.jpg","images/tabs04_off.jpg","images/tabs04_on.jpg","images/tabs05_off.jpg","images/tabs05_on.jpg","images/tabs06_off.jpg","images/tabs06_on.jpg","images/tabs07_off.jpg","images/tabs07_on.jpg","images/17.jpg","images/22.jpg","images/24.jpg","images/28.jpg","images/30.jpg","images/31.jpg","images/38.jpg" );
$(
    function()
        {
            // set up rollover  -- this controls the hover states
            $("img.rollover").hover(
                function()
                    {

                    var image_id=$(this).attr("data-image"); // created a variable, making this an Jquery wrapped object.
                    this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
                    $('#changeImg').css("background-image", "url(images/"+ image_id +'.jpg)'); 
                    $("#default_img").hide();


                    $(this).attr("id"); 
                    if (!(this.id == "defaultTab") ){
                        document.getElementById("defaultTab");
                        console.log();
                     $(this.id)[0].src.replace("_on","_off");
                      console.log('img.defaultTab');
                    }

                },
            function()
                {
                    this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
                }
        );
    }
```

)

My html piece is:

```
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td width="629"><img src="images/tabs01_on.jpg" class="rollover" data-image="28" width="89" height="55" id="defaultTab" /><img src="images/tabs02_off.jpg" class="rollover" data-image="24" width="91" height="55" /><img src="images/tabs03_off.jpg" class="rollover" data-image="30" width="90" height="55" /><img src="images/tabs04_off.jpg" class="rollover" data-image="22" width="89" height="55" /><img src="images/tabs05_off.jpg" class="rollover" data-image="17" width="91" height="55" /><img src="images/tabs06_off.jpg" class="rollover" data-image="38"  width="90" height="55" /><img src="images/tabs07_off.jpg" class="rollover" data-image="31" width="90" height="55" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will replace _off with _on when you are hovering, and replace _on with _off when you are not hovering.

Turn off default if you hover on another tab, if you are not hovering, then default will be on.

```
$('.rollover').not('#defaultTab').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace("_off","_on"));
    $('#defaultTab').attr('src',$('#defaultTab').attr('src').replace("_on","_off"));
},function(){
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace("_on","_off"));
    $('#defaultTab').attr('src',$('#defaultTab').attr('src').replace("_off","_on"));
});
```

If you want the last item someone hovered on to stay 'on' instead of the default being 'on', then you can use this instead:

```
$('.rollover').hover(function(){
    var hovered = $(this); // save the element we hovered on to use below.
    $('.rollover').each(function(){  
        var tab = $(this); // $(this) in here is each tab as we go through all of them, not the one we hovered on
        tab.attr('src',tab.attr('src').replace("_on","_off")); // Turn off ALL tabs.
    }
    hovered.attr('src',hovered.attr('src').replace("_off","_on")); // Turn on the tab we hovered on
},function(){ return false; });
```

Comment: I am getting an error from the console that the src is not defined.

Comment: src should be in quotes (a string literal)

Comment: This will turn off the tab when I hover over it, but i need the tab that has the id of defaultTab to turn off if any other button is hovered over.

Comment: Updated answer. This will now turn off the default tab if you hover on any others. If you do not hover on anything, default tab will be on. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I want to use the second one but i am receiving a syntax error.  Is something else supposed to go in the empty function at the bottom?

Comment: Also can you explain why this code works?  I see you have the $(this).attr called twice in the same line of code.  Why?

Comment: The empty function is what will run when you move your mouse off the tab (not hovering), if we remove this, then jquery will run the first function on hover on and hover off. You can enter 'return false;' in the empty function if that is the reason for the syntax error - if not can you tell me the error you get? [keep pressing enter to put  anew line :( ] Anyway, the $(this) is called to reference the element we are using, as we want to update it with a change in its own src, you could save it to a seperate var if you like (and you probably should, so have updated the code for all of this).

Comment: The code works great, it was just missing ) at the first closing }.

Comment: From my understanding, you put the hover event into a variable. Then you had the jquery go through all the "this" tabs and make sure they are off.  Then the src (source) of the hovered event is turned on.

Comment: Yes, it turns all of the tabs off, before turning the hovered one on. Accept answer if this is what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Now that I completely understood the problem, here is my suggestion:

You can search for the image, which contains `_on` in its `src` attribute (see the [*Attribute Contains Selector*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)) and change the value. E.g. (only including relevant code):

```
function toggle(element, on) {
    var from = on ? '_off' : '_on',
        to = on ? '_on' : '_off';

    element.attr('src', function(i, src) {
        return src.replace(from, to);
    });
}


$("img.rollover").hover(function(){
    toggle($('img.rollover[src*="_on"]'), false);
    toggle($(this), true);
}, function() {
    toggle($(this), false);
});
```

Then you don't even need to mark the default image with an ID.

---

I am not quite sure what you mean with *take defaultTabs image*. If `this` refers to the image, you can simple do:

```
if (this.id === "defaultTab"){
    this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
}
```

If on the other hand, the image is a descendant of `this`, you have to use `find`:

```
if (this.id == "defaultTab"){
    $(this).find('img').attr(src, function(i, value) {
        return value.replace("_on","_off");
    });
}
```

Note that the same ID can only be assigned to one element, not to multiple ones.

Comment: This will take turn off whatever button I am on.  I already have this functionality. I need for this to point to whatever .src defaultTab comes from.

Comment: I'm not really getting it... `defaultTab` is one of the images. Now that you posted your code and HTML, it seems you are after the first snippet I posted. It will only replace the URL if the elements ID is `defaultTab`... if this does not help you, then you have to explain your problem better.

Comment: ok, no problem. I have 7 buttons.  One of them when you load the page is already on the "on" state by default.  Right now, when I hover over it, it turns off.  When I hover over the other buttons they turn on.  The problem I have is, if I don't hover over the default button, it wont turn off.  So if a user chooses to hover over another button instead of the one that's already on, two buttons end up being highlighted.  I need some kind of function that will tell the on button to turn off if any other button beside it is selected.  hope this is clearer.  thanks

Comment: The code doesn't work but it's giving me a syntax error. I am tyring to debug but I am not sure what is failing.

Comment: I decided to use the other code below, but I am grateful for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you cant use `.src`  you need to use `.attr('src',new_href)`

Comment: he is calling .src on the DOM element, not a jQuery element, so .src is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time understanding your logic, but perhaps something like:

```
$(this).mouseenter(function() {
    if (this.id != 'defaultTab') {
        return;
    }
    this.src = this.src.replace(/_on/g,'_off');
});
```

Comment: Defaulttab is automatically highlighted when the page loads.  I just want it to turn off if anything else is hovered.  I already have the code set up to turn off and on the images states based on a hover.